# Converting a SQL subquery to a join for performance gains

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have a subquery with an inner join, This join is meant to cut down the data size to a more manageable size, before extracting data via an unpivot which has a further join to only pull out relevant matches..

When i've looked at the execution plan, it seems like the outer select is being executed first and thus taking an inordinate amount of time to complete as it is processing the data for all gamers instead of the cut down cohort..

this is the query

```
SELECT 
t2.Gamer_ID,
C.Feature_Code,
C.Feature_Name,
t2.CODE_DATE

FROM
(
SELECT
CAST(A.Gamer_ID
,[Identification_Code_Code_1]
,[Identification_Code_Code_2]
,[Identification_Code_Code_3]
,[Identification_Code_Code_4]
,[Identification_Code_Code_5]
,[Identification_Code_Code_6]
,[Identification_Code_Code_7]
,[Identification_Code_Code_8]
,[Identification_Code_Code_9]
,[Identification_Code_Code_10]
,CAST(Joining_date AS DATE) AS CODE_DATE
FROM Gamer_Characteristics A
INNER JOIN Gamer_Population P ON P.Gamer_ID = A.Gamer_ID --cuts down the number of gamers to the selected cohort


) s
unpivot (CODE for col in (
[Identification_Code_Code_1]
,[Identification_Code_Code_2]
,[Identification_Code_Code_3]
,[Identification_Code_Code_4]
,[Identification_Code_Code_5]
,[Identification_Code_Code_6]
,[Identification_Code_Code_7]
,[Identification_Code_Code_8]
,[Identification_Code_Code_9]
,[Identification_Code_Code_10])) as t2

INNER JOIN Gamer_feature_Code C ON C.CODE = LEFT(t2.CODE,C.CODE_LENGTH) --join to a dimension table to pull through characteristcs based on code and code length

WHERE

T2.CODE_DATE <= '2020-03-31'

GROUP BY t2.Gamer_ID,
C.Feature_Code,
C.Feature_Name,
t2.CODE_DATE
```

I have two questions.

1: can this be converted to use a join instead of subquery
2: Can i force the inner join in the subquery to take precedence over the inner join in the outer select?

Comment: Using cross apply vs unpivot will help.

Comment: Interesting, i hadn't realised you could use cross apply to unpivot